# In House distribution provisioning profiles for this account will be available two weeks after program activation

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

I purchased an enterprise developer program on 23rd, July 2016. When I try to create an In-house distribution provisioning profile it is giving an error as follows:

> In House distribution provisioning profiles for this account will be
>   available two weeks after program activation

Is there anyway to create distribution provisioning profile before this timeline? Please suggest me to resolve this situation.

Comment: has the same problem, did you find the solution?
is it after 2 weeks okay?

Comment: I contacted apple support team.They simply said that you have to wait for two weeks. After two weeks I could do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I contacted apple support team.They simply said that you have to wait for two weeks. After two weeks I could do that.

Answer (score 2):

Apple manually verifies companies, which enroll for the Enterprise Program. This check can take up to two weeks. This is not documented anywhere, but we found it out after calling the Apple support. If you have **very** pressing reasons, they **might** be able to put your company at the top of the review cue. Good luck.

Comment: This happens after Apple verifies everything and gets the account set up.