# In house distribution provisioning profiles will be available two weeks after program activation

Tags: ios, itunes, enterprise, ad-hoc-distribution, in-house-distribution

Our company has registered for a Apple enterprise account. WE want to distribute an app only within our organization. We have now created the app Id and distribution certificate for the app. But while creating a "In-House" provisioning profile we get the message :-

```
In house distribution provisioning profiles will be available two weeks after program activation
```

The app distribution is on priority. We do get an option to create an "Ad-Hoc" provisioning profile. Can we go ahead by signing the app with an Adhoc provisioning profile for now and distribute the app internally. Also later can we sign it using the In-house profile once that is available after 2 weeks?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to get UDID of every device to whom you want to distribute app with AdHoc profile.

Comment: @Dev_Tandel Thanks for the reply. Is this the case even with the Enterprise program?

Comment: Yes, AdHoc certificates are provided so you can distribute the app to your testers. It's never meant to be for actual distribution purpose

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In House distribution provisioning profiles for this account will be available two weeks after program activation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38538687/in-house-distribution-provisioning-profiles-for-this-account-will-be-available-t)

Answer (score 0):

My enterprise account was not enabled for in-house app distribution. As  https://stackoverflow.com/users/3548469/dev-tandel mentioned,

[image]

But I have an option to create adhoc certificate by registering the devices if you don't have any. Only limited devices can be installed. Reference screenshot is attached

[image]